# Why is selector being sent to previous view controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have an app with a data model class that declares a protocol, and two view controllers embedded in a navigation controller. The data model class is a shared instance. Both view controllers are delegates of the data model. The second view controller has a UITableView.

On start, calls to data model functions from the first view controller work as expected. When I segue from the first view controller to the second, calls to data model functions work as expected as well.

However, when I navigate back to the first view controller and a data model function is called, the app crashes with this error:

> 2017-04-03 09:48:12.623027 CoreDataTest[3207:1368182]
>   -[CoreDataTest.PracticesViewController noDupeWithResult:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15fe136e0

That PracticesViewController is the second view controller. I don't understand why a selector is being sent to what I am thinking of as the previous view controller. My expectation is that the selector should be sent to the first view controller that has just been navigated back to,

I am self-taught, so I presume there is something basic that I am missing, but I don't know what I don't know. Can someone explain why the crash is happening?

Code for the data model

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
import UIKit

@objc protocol PracticesDataDelegate {

    @objc optional func practicesLoadError(headline:String,message:String)
    @objc optional func practicesLoaded(practices:[NSManagedObject])
    @objc optional func practiceStored()
    @objc optional func practiceDeleted()
    @objc optional func noDupe(result:String)
}

class PracticesDataModel {

    static let sharedInstance = PracticesDataModel()
    private init () {}
    var delegate: PracticesDataDelegate?
    var practices: [NSManagedObject] = []

   // some code omitted . . .

/// Check for a duplicate exercise
func checkForDupe(title:String,ngroup:String,bowing:String,key:String){

    guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }

    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Practice")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "exTitle == %@ AND notegroup == %@ AND bowing == %@ AND key == %@", title, ngroup, bowing, key)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    do {
        practices = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

        if practices.count == 0 {
            self.delegate?.noDupe!(result:"none")  // exception happens here
        } else {
            self.delegate?.noDupe!(result:"dupe")
        }

    } catch let error as NSError {

        // to come
    }

}
```

The top of the first view controller

```
import UIKit

class galamianSelection: UIViewController, ExcerciseDataModelDelegate,    PracticesDataDelegate {

let exerciseModel = ExerciseDataModel.sharedInstance
let pModel = PracticesDataModel.sharedInstance

// some code omitted . . .

//// THE VIEW ////
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    exerciseModel.delegate = self
    pModel.delegate = self
    exerciseModel.loadExercises()
}

//// RESPOND TO PRACTICE DATA MODEL ////

func practiceStored() {
    print("exercise stored")
}

func noDupe(result: String) {
    if result == "none" {

        let d = Date()

        pModel.storePractice(date: d, exTitle: theExerciseTitle.text!, notegroup: theNoteGroup.text!, bowing: theBowings.text!, rythem: theRhythms.text!, key: theKey.text!, notes: "")

    } else {

        print("dupe")

    }
}
```

The top of the second view controller

```
import UIKit

class PracticesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,      UITableViewDataSource, PracticesDataDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

let pModel = PracticesDataModel.sharedInstance

// some code omitted . . .

//// THE VIEW ////

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pModel.delegate = self
    pModel.getPractices()
}
```

delegate is properly set to `self` in both view controllers.

I am happy to provide more code is needed, but I suspect someone who knows can diagnose from what I've provided.

Comment: Post the code for each view controller where you set the delegate.

Comment: The error is pretty clear: The corresponding method `noDupeWithResult` of the selector is missing in `PracticesViewController`. The class `PracticesDataModel` is irrelevant.

Comment: @Dima - additional code provided. @vadian - well yes, but why should `noDupe` need to be in the second view controller? After going back, `checkForDupe` is being called from the FIRST view controller not the second. Should't the selector be sent to the view controller that called the data model function?

Comment: Either way, with this line: `self.delegate?.noDupe!(result:"none")` you are forcing the code to call an optional delegate method that doesn't appear to show up in either one of your delegates. As to why it's calling one ViewController vs the other, I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

1. You are trying to reuse a delegate but only setting it in `viewDidLoad`. `viewDidLoad` is only called when, as the name implies, the view initially loads. That means that if you have VC1 in a navigation controller, then you push to VC2, then pop back to VC1, `viewDidLoad` will *not* be called a second time. The view has already loaded. If you want a piece of code to be called every time a view controller comes back into focus, you should put it into `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:`
2. You are force unwrapping an optional protocol method which you haven't actually implemented (a bug which you're seeing as a result of the first issue, but it's still an issue on its own). Change the force unwrap to an optional `self.delegate?.noDupe?(result:"none")`
3. You also declared your delegate like this `var delegate: PracticesDataDelegate?`. This makes your class retain its delegate and is generally not the right behavior. In your case it actually causes a retain cycle (until you change the delegate). You should change this declaration to `weak var delegate: PracticesDataDelegate?`

Comment: Thanks Dima. I have only just started to create and use delegates ( as I am sure is obvious to the more experienced) and there's a learning curve.  I had guessed at the first issue and tried the fix suggested, it did not work for me, but I'll try again with the other two issues in mind. It think is was Xcode that insisted on the `!` Some of the code prompting is a trap for the unwary.

Comment: Made the changes. All works as expected now. x1000 thanks Dima.

Answer (score 0):

What appears to be happening is:

- In `PracticesViewController` you set the model's delegate to `self`, as in `pModel.delegate = self`.
- You navigate back to your first view controller. This means that `PracticesViewController` gets deallocated. But the model's delegate has not been changed, so it's still pointing to the memory location where the view controller used to be.
- Later (but soon), your model tries to call a method on its delegate, but it can't because it was deallocated. This crashes your app.

You could reassign the value of the delegate, for example in `viewDidAppear`. Or you could have your model check whether its delegate implements a method before attempting to call it. That's a standard practice for `optional` protocol methods-- since they don't have to be implemented, you check first before calling them.

In general, don't use `!` in Swift unless you want your code to crash there if something goes wrong.

Comment: Actually Tom, the code in the question has the delegate as a non-optional, so that isn't quite *the* problem ( but it is a problem). The VC is never getting deallocated, the delegate is just wrong.